# Get database structure

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite

I have a task to check the database for updated fields, primary keys, foreign keys, constraints and triggers. And if some change update tables.
I found such a thing **Schema** but I have littel informaition(only fields and primary keys).
May suggest how get more information from database or other way.Thanks!

```
SQLiteConnection sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Test.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"); 
sql_con.Open();

SQLiteCommand sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
sql_cmd.CommandText = "select * from Clients";
SQLiteDataReader myReader = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader();

DataTable schema = myReader.GetSchemaTable();
foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in schema.Columns)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(col.ColumnName + " = " + row[col]+"\n"+
            "Null value allowed: " + col.AllowDBNull);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite databases, you have all schema information via system table `sqlite_master`.

Comment: Where I can find sqlite_master ?

Comment: You can access it like any other table in your database: `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master`